# Request: mouse squeaks

Tags: request, animals, mouse

hello,

does anyone have a few mouse squeaks they are willing to share? im not sure what i have to trade, but i smashed a TV in an old warehouse once with some cool results, and i have a few ZOOM shopping centre walla/ambience with no music, or in a few cases very little music that you cant understand.

if not i might just see if i could get a useable result at a pet store, but im not to sure how often they actually squeak.

if someone has some ideas to recreate a mouse squeak, i would love to hear it too.

cheers
Jamie

Comment: thanks all, for your input i will try these things tonight and if not prob head dow to the local pet store.

cheers

Answer (score 2):

I have a bird caller, which consists of a wooden bead around a metal shaft - it's amazingly good for making a variety of bird chirps and squeaky noises. They are easy to pick up a outdoor type stores.

Not sure how mousey that would sound, but I'm happy to post a recording if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

Make your way to the local pet store. Talk to the owner / manager about what you need and why you need it; you will probably find them willing to help and interested in what you need the sounds for.

Also, try guinea pigs, hamsters and gerbils.

Comment: Please don't torture them to get the squeaks out of them :(

Comment: Take a photo of a cat to show them, for a bit of motivation :)

Answer (score 1):

Get one of those stools that you twist/spin to raise higher or lower - like a piano stool. One that is squeeky is easy to manipulate and I'm sure you can re-create a sound like that if you manipulate something like that with pitch shifting it up.

Otherwise, did you try searching Sound Dogs?

Answer (score 1):

Get some car brakes.  Everytime I listen to a zoom recording of traffic, I hear all these new squeaks and I think they are car brakes.

Answer (score 1):

wet rubber soled shoes make great squeaks and are very controllable.

an old pad lock with some extra sand in the latch will usually give out really nice squeaks as well.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite mouse squeaks came from pitch-shifted puppy yips.  Find some clean puppy yips, and  pitch shift them up without time compensation and you'll find some really neat and natural sounding mouse squeaks.

I used a stock puppy yap track from the Hollywood Edge (yeah, I know) and it came out rather nice on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

I have got some good mouse squeaks by quickly sliding my fingers over a sheet of glass

Answer (score 0):

I use a selection of latex squeaky dog balls.